# Python multiprocessing children hang -- BOTO3 PARAMIKO

Tags: python, python-3.x, multiprocessing, boto3, paramiko

Thanks in advance for any help....I'm stuck!  I am attempting to write a script that will fire up many processes that each do the following: 
    1. spin up an AWS EC2 Instance 
    2. execute a script on that instance (script sitting there on AMI)
    3. terminate instance when script complete

Using separate VMs really is necessary and this is not be a good case for another type of parallelism locally.

The script below works but the pool workers stop responding.  I get part of the way through the target_cos list and the pool workers do nothing.  The process they live in is still running and the VM is still alive on AWS but nothing happens and things appear to be hung.

Additionally, when I step through it using a debugger/IDE with a single pool worker it works correctly.  When I run it with many workers in the mp pool, they hang after ~2 iterations.

```
import postgresql
import boto3
import paramiko
import time
import os
from multiprocessing import Pool


def spin_up(target_co):
    #What would happen with paramiko import here?

    ec2 = boto3.resource('ec2', region_name="us-west-2")
    instances = ec2.create_instances(ImageId='AMI-HERE',
                                 MinCount=1,
                                 MaxCount=1,
                                 KeyName="SECRET_KEY",
                                 InstanceType="t2.micro",
                                 Placement={
                                     'AvailabilityZone': 'us-west-2c'
                                 },
                                 SecurityGroups=[
                                     'Internal'
                                 ]
                                 )
    i = instances[0]

    print('WAITING FOR INSTANCE AVAILABILITY....')
    i.wait_until_running()
    print('OK.')

    i.load()

    k = paramiko.RSAKey.from_private_key_file('KEY_FILE_PATH.pem')
    c = paramiko.SSHClient()
    c.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())

    success_flag = False
    attempt_counter = 0
    while success_flag == False and attempt_counter < 20:
        try:
            c.connect(hostname=i.public_dns_name, username="ubuntu", pkey=k)
            success_flag = True
        except:
            print('SSH Error.....Retrying.')
            attempt_counter += 1
            time.sleep(5)

    cmd = "python3 PATH_TO_EXECUTABLE_ON_AMI.py --target {} > LOG_FILE_ON_VM".format(target_co)

    transport = c.get_transport()
    channel = transport.open_session()
    channel.exec_command(cmd)

    while(channel.exit_status < 0):
        print(str(os.getpid()) + '  sleeping...')
        time.sleep(60)

    print('Terminating Instance....')
    i.terminate()
    print('Exiting....')


if __name__ == '__main__':

     target_cos = ['539',
              '542',
              '528',
              '48',
              '536',
              '26',
              '7',
              '20572',
              '10',
              '20',
              '101',
              '10023']

    # PARALLEL
    with Pool(processes=2) as pool:
        pool.map_async(spin_up, iter(target_cos))

        #are these actually required?
        pool.close()
        pool.join()
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to open a channel, or sleep. Just do `client.exec_command()`. It will block until it is finished.

I ran your code like this:

```
import paramiko
import time
from multiprocessing import Pool


def spin_up(target_co):
    c = paramiko.SSHClient()
    c.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())

    success_flag = False
    attempt_counter = 0
    while success_flag == False and attempt_counter < 20:
        try:
            c.connect(hostname='localhost', username="user", password='pass')
            success_flag = True
        except:
            print('SSH Error.....Retrying.')
            attempt_counter += 1
            time.sleep(5)

    cmd = "hostname"

    stdin, stdout, stderr = c.exec_command(cmd)

    print(stdout.read())
    print(stderr.read())
    print(stdout.channel.recv_exit_status())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    target_cos = ['539',
                  '542',
                  '528',
                  '48',
                  '536',
                  '26',
                  '7',
                  '20572',
                  '10',
                  '20',
                  '101',
                  '10023']

with Pool(processes=2) as pool:
    pool.map(spin_up, iter(target_cos))
```

I don't have the Amazon stuff so I can't test that. You can use map instead of map_async because you don't need to do anything after you start the processes. You can just block until it is finished.

If you still have issues, try changing your pool to a TreadPool. Forking and treading at the same time can cause issues. If you still have issues after that you might want to look at AsyncSSH. It will let you do this with Asyncio which is Python's cool new Async library.

Forgot to mention: you are forking and threading because multiprocessing uses forking and Paramiko uses threads.

Comment: Thanks for your response, I appreciate it.  I'm still doing some research, and will follow up here when I get this solved.

Comment: Did you solve this @TravisMillburn?  It seems you should use multiple sessions when doing multiprocessing.

I tried this, but the session startup was slower than waiting for the objects to download with the boto3 library blocking, so it made things slower, not faster..
https://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/guide/resources.html#multithreading-multiprocessing

Currently I'm thinking the only way forward might be to pre-create the boto sessions/resources, so I can run the hits fast, but this seems fraught and ugly...

I'm doing download source image, scale it, then zip the results in loop